# jQuery color animations relative to the elements' current color (hue, saturation, brightness)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, colors

I want to do color animations without explicitly specifying absolute colors. To give you an example:

I have a `div` with `background: #2288ee`. If i want to make it brighter, instead of writing:

```
$('div').animate({'background-color': '#3399ff'});
```

i want to write something like:

```
$('div').brighten({'background-color': '10%'});
```

The core of the idea is to have relative values in case the design changes and i do not have to adjust every single effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may checkout this repository, it supports all your requirements.(hue, saturation, brightness, etc)

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color